# How to test removing uploaded file in jest and testing library

Tags: reactjs, input, file-upload, jestjs, testing-library

I am not sure how to test removing uploaded file in jest and testing library.

I have used this, but not working for me.

```
    const input = container.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
    userEvent.upload(input, file);

    expect(input.files[0]).toStrictEqual(file);
    expect(input.files.item(0)).toStrictEqual(file);
    expect(input.files).toHaveLength(1);   //this was passed.

    userEvent.clear(input);
    expect(input.files).toHaveLength(0);   //this was issued. length is 1.
```

if someone has experience with this part, please publish your experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fireEvent` from `@testing-library/react` like so (this is in TypeScript):

```
import { fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";

import MyButton from "components/MyButton";

describe("File input component", () => {
  it("successfully clears the input and calls the `onChange` method", async () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<MyButton />);

    // get the file input
    const fileInput = getByTestId("button-upload-input") as HTMLInputElement;
    expect(fileInput).toBeInstanceOf(HTMLInputElement);

    // add a file to the input
    await userEvent.upload(fileInput, YOUR_TEST_FILE);

    // ⬇⬇⬇ The change method to clear the input file and trigger `onChange` ⬇⬇⬇
    fireEvent.change(fileInput, { target: { files: [] } });

    // assert that the file input was cleared as expected
    expect(fileInput.files).toHaveLength(0);
  });
});
```